# Como pegar uma parte de uma imagem?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Com base nessa imagem como seria o código para separar em, como se fosse sub imagem sem dividir essa imagem em arquivos diferentes:

[image: THEMED_CONTROL_BOX_WINDOWS_FIXED]

Ex:

```
void splitImage(int numeroDeDivisoes, ref Image original, out Image[] final){
// aqui seria que nem essa imagem acima sendo dividida em Rectangle sem dividir o arquivo.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) da classe *System.Drawing.Bitmap*.

O exemplo seguinte cria um *Bitmap* correspondente à parte definida pelo retângulo cujo canto superior esquerdo tem como coordenadas 0,0 com um comprimento e largura igual a 100:

```
Rectangle cloneRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format = myBitmap.PixelFormat;
Bitmap cloneBitmap = myBitmap.Clone(cloneRect, format);
```

No caso presente `myBitmap` é o seu `PictureBox.Image` obtido da seguinte forma:
<sub>(Não tenho a certeza se o *cast* é possível, mas julgo que sim.)</sub>

```
Bitmap myBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
```

ou

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
```