# Como pegar parte de uma imagem usando bitmap C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Galera, eu estou estudando bitmaps, e baixei um pdf qual dizia que uma imagem era uma matriz de pixels. Já que é uma matriz(oque é bem logico) existe como definir pontos dentro da imagem, marcar uma região digamos assim. A classe bitmap como bem devem saber ler as propriedades de uma imagem, como o "tamanho" dela, gostaria de saber se há algum jeito de marcar pontos como 200 x 200(exemplo) e salvar essa região em uma nova imagem.

A imagem do Braum, personagem do jogo League of Legends, é aleatoria e essa marca em negro é para mostrar oque seria essa região qual me refiro.

Ps: Obrigado Renan, a sua resposta ajudou muito, resolvi mudar a pergunta para que ela ficasse aberta e mais repostas sejam dadas.

[image: Essa foto é totalmente aleatoria e essa marca em negro fiz apenas para mostrar oque quis dizer como "região"]

Comment: Só a parte do preto, seria o que esse preto? um outro componente?

Comment: @bigown Eu tava no meio da resposta quando a pergunta foi fechada :(

Comment: Ah @Renan essas perguntas são péssimas, a pessoas fala "eu quero fazer isso, se vira aí para responder tudo". Tá até escrito na ajuda que essas perguntas são ruins e devem ser fechadas. E pode ser fechada por vários motivos, é igual a um exercício de escola, o que pode se mesmo, é ampla porque não diz como quer, é não clara porque falta informações do que precisa e até baseada em opiniões porque cada um fará do jeito que achar melhor, embora eu acho que a ampla se encaixa melhor.

Comment: @Carlos não é possível responder aqui porque a pergunta foi fechada, mas abri um fiddle com exemplo e explicação (em comentário): https://dotnetfiddle.net/ooOmz9

Comment: Eu posso reabrir, mas se eu fizer isso eu praticamente paro de moderar, porque fica complicado eu fazer o que sempre foi definido como deve ser o site e eu ter que ficar abrindo exceção porque alguém quer responder algo que deveria ser fechado. Eu até abri debate https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6207/101

Comment: @bigown eu não acho que seja uma pergunta problemática. Existem diversas perguntas do tipo no SO em inglês e são bem aceitas por lá. Eu mesmo sou um dos usuários mais ativos nas filas de revisão. Acontece que esse tipo de dúvida nessa pergunta é muito comum, e tendo uma pergunta com uma resposta canônica nós podemos sempre direcionar as pessoas para cá.

Comment: @Renan isso vale para qualquer pergunta de escola, ela nunca atendeu os critérios do site. O SO nem dá pra se basear porque já não há controle lá, não há senso de comunidade, é sempre um grupo que está ativo no momento que acaba agindo de acordo com o momento que é o que acho que queremos evitar aqui.

Comment: @bigown você está certo a pergunta realmente tinha ficado ruim e temo que ainda esteja, a todo caso você como moderador tem direito de fechar a pergunta se ela não obedecer as regras do site.

Comment: Relacionado(duplicata?): [Como pegar uma parte de uma imagem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59257/2541)